# xamarin android json response

Tags: android, json, xamarin, json.net

I have got problem with json Response in my new Json file.

```
Task<string> downloadTask = httpClient.GetStringAsync(myJsonFile);
            string content = await downloadTask;
            var Messages = new List<NotificationClass>();
            JObject jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(content);
            IList<JToken> results = jsonResponse["Messages"].ToList();
```

//That's my old working json file

```
"Messages":[
{"MessageID" : "1",
"Name" : "Test",
"Subject" : "Subject",
"Message" : "Message",
"DateTimeCreated" : "19/03/2016"
},
{
"MessageID" : "2",
"Name" : "Test2",
"Subject" : "Subject2",
"Message" : "Message2",
"DateTimeCreated" : "18/03/2016"
}]
```

However, I want to get response from json without the header "Messages" like code below
Is it still possible? What should I use in `JsonResponse["?"].ToList();`

```
[{"MessageID" : "1",
"Name" : "Test",
"Subject" : "Subject",
"Message" : "Message",
"DateTimeCreated" : "19/03/2016"
},
{
"MessageID" : "2",
"Name" : "Test2",
"Subject" : "Subject2",
"Message" : "Message2",
"DateTimeCreated" : "18/03/2016"
}]
```

Thanks.
Damian.

Comment: Do you have any control over the server?  It not, then your only approach is to modify the client json when you deserialize it, which is what you are already doing.

Comment: Thank you:) That's mean that would be better to use it that case my old working json file rather than try to get the other working right? What's the best possible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your original json, the list of messages was inside a field called "messages". That's why you needed to do [messages] to obtain the JToken corresponding to the body of the "messages" key.

Since now you have directly a list on the higher level, it's probably easier to just fall down to using JsonConvert directly, deserializing your string into a List of Message objects (Having Message be a class having fields named MessageID, Name, Subject, etc.).

```
List<Message> message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Message>>(content);
```

Be aware, also, that if you follow this approach, and your Message class has fields with slightly different name than the Json, you will need to add annotations for providing the proper name to the parse, like:

```
[JsonProperty("MessageID")]
public string MessageId { get; set; }
```

In any case, if you'd rather to the parsing some other way, it's probably better to just keep your old json when possible, mostly because named fields are always preferred to just having keyless-nameless objects.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. However, when I do so I have got an error "JObject doesnt contain a definition for ToList"

Comment: @fisher1 I have updated my answer with a different approach.

Comment: Thank you :) I tried to use suggested solution but I'm getting an error Cannot implicitly convert type 'namespace.Message' to 'System.Collection.Generic List<namespace.Message>'

Comment: Sorry, there was a small typo in the line of code, I updated the answer :)

Comment: Thanks. Great Solution that's what I was looking for!